# Gain or Loss in simple way?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A person sells an article at a profit of 10% If he had bought it at 10% less and sold it for 3 dollars more ,he would have gained 25%.Find the Cost price.

My solution is

120

I derived to the solution by fraction method 
let $x$ be the cost price 
Actual selling price is $(110/100) x$
Supposed cost price $x(90/100)$.
Supposed selling price is $x(90/100) (125/100)$.

so 
$$
x(110/100)+3=x(90/100)(125/100)
$$

so

$$
x=120
$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: Please see the edits now and help me with other ways of solving it sir ! It took me more than a hour to come with this solution !

Comment: Your answer is perfectly fine.

Comment: Your answer is correct, and that's not an accident. Your method is a good one. The next time you see a problem like this you will do it in a few minutes, not an hour. (Note my edits to your question, displaying the mathematics better. Do that yourself next time you visit to ask or answer a question.)